# Jython - Scala array/list not JSON serializable within python script

Tags: java, python, scala, avro, jython

I have a Scala class that wraps an avro record with getters and setters. Using Jython to allow users to write python scripts to process the Avro record and ultimately do a `json.dumps` on the new processed record.

The issue is, if the user wants to grab a value that is an Array from the record, the interpreter complains that the object is not JSON serializable.

```
import json
json.dumps(<AClass>.getArray('myArray'))
```

The AClass is made available to any given python script at run time. Scala AClass:

```
class AClass {
  def getArray(fieldName: String): Array[Integer] = { 
    val value: GenericData.Array[T] = [....]
        value
      .asInstanceOf[GenericData.Array[T]]
      .asScala
      .toArray[T]
  }
}
```

I've tried a few other return types, 1) `List[Integer]`, 2) `mutable.Buffer[Integer]`, just the plain Avro generic Array 3) `GenericData.Array[T]`. All give the same serialization error with the slightly varying objects:

1. `Runtime exception occurred during Python processing. TypeError: List(1, 2, 3) is not JSON serializable.`
2. `... Buffer(1, 2, 3) is not JSON serializable`
3. `... [1, 2, 3] is not JSON serializable.`

Now it seems that if we were to convert it to a `list()` from within the python script, it works fine. This gave some leads but need it to happen at the Scala level.

```
import json
json.dumps(list(<AClass>.getArray('myArray')))
```

Is there any way to achieve this? What Scala / Java list type would translate directly into the python `list` type and/or be JSON serializable within the Jython py interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

The json module in jython only accepts standard jython data types (that's why converting to list() works). See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table

Comment: is it possible to do a conversion from the Scala code so the type is a python `list`?

Comment: You may be able to return a PyList from Scala to jython.  For code examples (in Java): https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.python.core.PyList/add